# psexec - Make sure that the default admin$ share is enabled on

Tags: cmd, psexec, remote-control

I have a problem when using psexec. I want to remote control windows cmd, but I get this error

> "Make sure that the default admin$ share is enabled on".

It connects successfully only when my computer and remote computer are under the same domain (router). But when my computer has a different IP, I will get this error even if the the command is totally the same. I have tried some solutions such as change register value, but still fails.  Plz help me!

Comment: It might be easier to use PowerShell. See `Invoke-Command` or `New-PSSession`.