# How to RDP connect to an Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I would like to run some tests on some VM machines. The machines belong to different users with different MSDN accounts, which means private passwords.

What I did was so far is to create an Azure VM for each MSDN account and set a similar user name/password for the machine.

What I would like to do is to:

1. Connect to any of these VMs. My problem: I don't know the machine name. I tried to connect using the rdp file provided by Azure, and it's working, but the problem is that it's using an IP instead of a name.
   I tried finding the machine name, but all documentation about this seems to be outdated. [image: This is how my machine description looks like]. I tried to connect to amam10x64.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com but without success.
2. Copy a file to/from the VM. My hope is that I can use the following snippet:

   $commandStr = [string]::Format("Copy-VMFile ""{0}"" -SourcePath ""{1}"" -
   DestinationPath ""{2}"" -CreateFullPath -FileSource Host -Force", $VM, 
   $SessionPath, $RemoteFullPath)
   $commandBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($commandStr)
   Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock $commandBlock
3. Run a command on the VM. Hopefully, I can use same command from Pt. 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to connect to amam10x64.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com but
>   without success.

If you want to connect this VM with DNS, we should set FQDN for this VM, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/portal-create-fqdn).

> Copy a file to/from the VM. My hope is that I can use the following
>   snippet:

Maybe we can use `winrm` to do this.
About how to use winrm connect Azure VM, please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45196104/how-connect-to-a-azure-windows-vm-and-run-a-remote-script-with-powershell/45207644#45207644).

> Run a command on the VM. Hopefully, I can use same command from Pt. 2.

We can use this script to connect Azure VM via `Winrm`:

```
$username = 'jason'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -string 'password' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $pass
$s = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri 'http://23.99.82.2:5985' -Credential $cred -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck)
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {Get-Process PowerShell}
```

Comment: I get a PS error: "New-PSSession : Relative URIs are not supported in the creation of remote sessions.". My code snippet is: $machineRemote='amam10x64.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com'
$username = 'user'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -string 'password' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $pass
$s = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri $machineRemote -Credential $cred -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck)

Comment: Ok, I added the port (:5985) and I fixed that error, but now I get a Firewall error. I wonder why I get this, since I already could connect with RDP: "WinRM cannot complete the
operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and
that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer."

Comment: I added an exception in Azure Networking (I think it's called NSG), and I ran the command "Enable-PSRemoting" on the VM. I still get the same error "WinRM cannot complete the
operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and
that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM
firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet.". Any thought?

Comment: @AndreiM Have you add port 5985 to your windows firewall?

Comment: shouldn't "Enable-PSRemoting" automatically do this?

Comment: @AndreiM maybe we should check the firewall settings

Comment: @AndreiM can you telnet that vm and port 5985?

Comment: I can't do telnet (), but I managed to fix the problem. For some reason, WinRM rule in NSG is opening port 5986 instead of 5985. Is this a bug?

Comment: I tried to use telnet (never used before), but I get an error (same happens if I use the FQDN name): telnet 13.80.120.45:5985
Connecting To 13.80.120.45:5985...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed

Comment: Many thanks for the help with investigating the issue, Jason. I managed to make everything working. I have one more question, though: I created a norepad process, but I noticed it's created in session 0. Is it possible to create the process in the user session, because I want to interact with existing applications.

Comment: @AndreiM for now, it is not possible:( I have test it many times, does not work. Run in the backend.

Comment: One last question, (I hope): I used psexec.exe from SysInternals in order to start a notepad in the user session. It worked somehow, in the sense that a process is created, it is visible in Taskbar, but the window is all a black rectangle, like it's not receiving some events like WM_PAINT. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @AndreiM Sorry, I am not good at SysInternals, but as far as I know, we can't use powershell remotely to open GUI like `calc`, `notepad`, by default those will running in the backend, as you say, we can find them in the taskbar.