# Powershell create folder on AzureVM

Tags: powershell, azure

I've been trying to create a folder on a list of vm's in Azure using powershell.

Within the VM's I can use the below which works

```
$c = Get-Credential -Credential domain\AdminUser
$Comp = Get-Content C:\temp\list.txt
$s = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.NewScriptBlock("mkdir c:\Whatyousaying")
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Comp -ScriptBlock $s -Credential $c
```

However I have tried a few things but it doesn't recognise the AzureVm path.

I have tried something like

```
$ComputerName = Get-AzureRmVM | select Name
$DriveLetter = "C"
$Path = "NewDirectory"

foreach ($ComputerNames in $ComputerName)
{
    New-Item -Path \\

$ComputerName\$DriveLetter$\$Path -type directory -Force 
}
```

I m missing something obvious, I'm thinking DNS not finding the servers, so Ive tried using the public ip name and address, but they failed with winRM error, but this works in Azure. I have checked using Enable-PSRemoting, which is already enabled.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you are missing the escape character ` 
to include $ in your share path. 
Change your New-Item line to New-Item "\\$ComputerName\$DriveLetter`$\$Path" . 
Tip: When you have issues with share paths, just change the command to Write-Host to make sure that it is the path that you want. 
Then you can take the output of that command and throw it into the Run Box to make sure it is valid. I apologize for the formatting. I could not get the back-tick to print correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, create a folder for Azure VM you can use `Winrm`.

About enable Azure VM winrm, you should add port **5985** to Azure **NSG** inbound rules and add port 5985 to **windows firewall** inbound rules.

You can use this script to create a session:

```
$username = 'user'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -string 'password' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $pass
$s = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:5985' -Credential $cred -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck)
```

About create new folder, you can use `invoke-command` to create it:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {new-item c:\newdirectory}
```

Also you need to filter Azure VMs' public IP addresses with Azure PowerShell.

Here [a similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45196104/how-connect-to-a-azure-windows-vm-and-run-a-remote-script-with-powershell/45207644#45207644) about you, via Winrm to run powershell command, please refer to it.